# Counsel-rg omit long maching line

Tags: emacs, ripgrep

I utilize the counsel-rg to search the pattern of "~[a-z]+~", it displays the desired results but omit long matching line:

[image]

How could enable it to get long-matching-line displayed?

Comment: That only happens when the `-M/--max-columns` flag is set when running ripgrep. So something somewhere is setting it.

Comment: ty, solved it. could you please transmit the comment to answer.

Comment: I can't. You should answer it. Only you know where that setting was and how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example usage:

```el
;; counsel-rg (&optional initial-input initial-directory extra-rg-args rg-prompt)
(defun ugt-counsel-rg ()
  "Add initial search text into minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((initial-input "^\\*+ ")    ;; Search only org headers
        (initial-directory "~/org")
        (extra-rg-args "--max-columns 300") ;; <== THIS
        (rg-prompt "rg: Search org file headers (narrow with =S-SPC= or =!keyword=: "))
    (counsel-rg initial-input
                initial-directory
                extra-rg-args
                rg-prompt)))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-u") 'ugt-counsel-rg)
```